# Post published although Youtube API return error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

**Getting this error in the failed post.**

```
{
 "code" : 503,
 "errors" : [ {
 "domain" : "global",
 "message" : "Backend Error",
 "reason" : "backendError"
 } ],
 "message" : "Backend Error"
}
```

Despite that the post got published.

Comment: My advice is search whether your problem is already reported on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) or report the problem there - since this is a problem from the YouTube Data API itself.